# Extract the column number which has the last data point from a table

Tags: r

I have the following inverted data frame

```
z
      Jan   Feb    Mar   Apr   May   Jun    Jul    Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov    Dec
14                     -8.70  0.28 18.66   4.81 -34.33 40.39  3.09  7.89  49.41
13  -6.10  9.51  -1.09 -0.01  7.89 -7.37  -0.61  -9.79 31.75 40.67  5.41 -10.53
12  -5.21  7.49  -7.92  3.54 11.19 -6.66  23.64  13.21  9.64 14.44 59.95 -20.96
11 -12.68 11.04 -11.10 -6.18 -5.61  8.93  94.99  30.15 14.37 31.08 -9.02 -14.77
10   5.07 -2.04  22.77 12.05  0.38 -3.28  -2.73  11.26  5.30  4.61 13.80   3.68
9   -0.82  0.86   3.18  1.06  6.47  1.57   2.25  -9.34  5.27  7.25  2.85   0.42
8   10.48  1.17  10.97 -0.13  0.32 -5.89  -2.26  -7.28 -1.39  3.35 14.81   3.40
7   -5.22  3.09  -7.75 -3.41 -0.09 12.37 -17.38   1.41  8.57 10.48 -1.20   7.45
6   13.85  7.22   3.14 -2.92 -7.12  0.45   3.51  -2.30  7.07 -2.83 -2.27  -1.52
5   -0.57  0.58  -2.59  3.29 -6.07  0.37   1.32  -0.58  4.07 -4.85 -0.48   1.66
4    0.46 -0.41   3.01  0.60  2.20 -2.39   0.22   3.99  5.50 16.07 -4.51   0.50
3    1.28  5.10  -3.61  5.02  3.04 -4.05  -2.64   1.88 -2.44  3.27 -2.71   2.02
2   -1.28  0.99   2.38  0.16  1.03 10.93   5.07   0.26  0.84 -0.05 -0.88  -3.71
1    2.33 -1.71  -0.41 -0.58 -2.19  1.26   1.88  -4.03  0.54  0.34  0.22  -0.50
```

I would like to find out which column has the last data point in this example -0.50 and extract the column name in this case Dec as a number (12), without using the -0.50 data point, tried wrong with the below expressions

```
which( colnames(z)==-0.50)
integer(0)
which( colnames(z)==z[length(z)])
integer(0)
```

Second example

```
      Jan   Feb    Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep    Oct   Nov   Dec
18                                                         -12.97  9.96  8.14
17   1.50  3.27   7.38 -1.63  8.53  2.97  1.51 10.99  4.51  -5.70  1.15  9.50
16  -1.38  3.61  -3.98 10.51 -8.39  5.29 -2.01 -3.47 -0.17  -6.20 13.93  9.04
15  -3.96  1.72  -3.28  2.06 -0.26 -1.27 -4.58  3.23 -7.76   2.09  7.33 16.81
14   4.38  0.56   7.09 -5.31 -2.61 -2.66  0.66  0.56  4.64  13.75 -7.10 -5.15
13 -10.13 -6.04  12.62 -3.76 -3.96  7.95  4.71  6.04  7.63  -7.96 -0.69 14.16
12   5.95 11.95 -10.80  2.45 10.19 -5.20 -0.68  0.62  0.26   4.72 -2.48 10.27
11   2.72 11.56  -0.80 -8.62  0.28 -2.96  1.33  3.09  5.14   4.03  6.37 -0.19
10  -5.38  6.58   4.64 -4.21  6.62  3.13 -1.85  7.63 -6.17  -2.95  7.32 -4.37
9    4.20 -2.58   4.01  5.66 -2.94 -1.17 -0.47  4.54 -1.10   1.48  3.24  2.14
8    3.86 -5.93  -3.95  6.46  5.05  1.91 -1.18 -0.88  6.99   2.52  2.42  0.24
7    3.85  7.95  -0.66 -0.99  1.99  5.06 -4.63 -3.00 -0.41   3.73  4.97  2.10
6    0.99 -0.21  -1.64 -3.01 -2.03 -1.26 -1.52  0.32  2.85  -1.59  5.12 -2.45
5   -2.64  2.33   4.91  1.75 -1.01  1.47 -2.78  4.78  0.94   2.51 -2.01  3.75
4    0.08  1.51   0.25  3.00 -2.16 -2.51  4.59  1.43  0.16  -2.59  0.97  1.65
3    0.63 -0.83  -0.68  0.12 -0.22 -3.17  4.41 -1.29 -2.18  -2.54  1.00  1.36
2    2.51  0.17   2.66  3.41 -2.40 -1.77 -0.63 -3.80  3.47   3.20  2.20  0.37
1   -2.37
```

Last point is Jan -2.37

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something like `which(z == -.5, arr.ind=TRUE)`? Your question isn't really clear. Also, look out for floating point problems with what you're describing.

Comment: I was looking to select the column where the last data point is and to extract the column name or its corresponding number as length(z) =12 however without the specific number as have to apply it to other tables.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. If @AnandaMahto's answer is not the one you are looking for, maybe you could simply use `ncol(z)`?

Comment: thanks for your time and appologies if the question is not clear. I am Looking to extract the column number that coincides with the last data point in z, if possible without using the data point -0.50 or using ncol(z) which happens to be the last column the same as the last data point.

Comment: What do you mean "last data point"?

Comment: -0.50 in this example

Comment: @Barnaby, you would have saved a lot of confusion by showing an example where the last value is not in the last column

Comment: Please `dput` your data so we can figure out exactly what we're dealing with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on @BrodieG's one.

You could try `nchar` to test for "empty cells":

```
tail(which(nchar(as.matrix(z)) == 0, arr.ind=TRUE), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Can I ask you the reason for the conversion into a matrix of z

Comment: @Barnaby: `nchar` counts the number of characters per column if you use a `data.frame`. To get the number of characters per cell I transform it into a `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

```
col <- max(which(!is.na(t(as.matrix(z))))) %% ncol(z)
if(!col) col <- ncol(z)
names(z)[[col]] 
# [1] "Dec"
```

This assumes "empty" values are NA, and that `z` is a data frame.  I tested this by removing some values from the end, and it worked as well.

Comment: You answer provides column 12 even when last data point is not Dec.

Comment: @Barnaby, are the empty data points `NA`?  If they are something else this obviously won't work, but can be updated to make it work if you provide more details on what the data is (`data.frame` with character, columns, etc).  What represents emptyness?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to read your bottom line no NAs. I can try to put NAs for the issue in question. z is a table unsure if this affects the result will try now with NAs

Comment: @Barnaby, the only data type `table` that I know is the one produced by `table()`, which can't be the same type as what you are showing.  What do you get when you do `str(z)`?

Comment: It is a data frame my appologies.

Comment: it does work with NAs. however I am unsure if is possible to have an  expression which calls for the last item in the dataframe and indexes its possition as per the row and column and then extract the column like in expression which(z == -.5, arr.ind=TRUE), however without the -0.5